# Как добавить функцию Зеркала и панорамы в API карт?

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

Как добавить функцию "зеркал" в API карт?
Чтобы в какой-то части экрана была возможность включить панораму или зеркал

Answer (score 1):

В API на сегодняшний день нет слоя Зеркал, а вот панорамы — пожалуйста. Плеер можно включить методом `ymaps.panorama.locate()` или `ymaps.panorama.createPlayer()`.

Также в коде вы можете задать, где показывать панораму: на весь экран или в каком-то своем UI-элементе, в примерах Яндекса есть [добавление панорамы в балун метки](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/panorama_in_balloon?from=SO).